# Server transfer CiviCRM search problems

Tags: search

We have just transferred a Wordpress installation of CiviCRM 5.21.0 to a new server, but all of the search functions are failing. In advanced search, when I attempt to open for example, "Address", the following error appears and repeats itself on some kind of loop:

"Because your session timed out, we have reset the search page."

The Address option then just opens up another "Search Criteria" section underneath.

The parameters in the looping message are:
page    "CiviCRM"
q   "civicrm/contact/search/advanced"
reset   "1"
snippet "json"

I've checked the database connection and that seems fine, it is returning the correct numbers of results in saved search smart group lists, but when I click "contacts" on the lists it shows no results, just the same error.

Answer (score 5):

I found the problem, the session save path in .htaccess was different from the one in the new CPanel.